# How can I make my cells rounded like in the App Store

Tags: ios, swift, collections, view, uicollectionview

[image: Screenshot]

I made CollectionViewCells, and I want the corners rounded like the App Store cells. I made the background different colours to see it better. also trying to do the same for the Image View

In the code below I tried to make the corner rounded, but the do not change.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // setup the cell and cast it to the custom cell created.
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.elementNameLabel.text = elemementName[indexPath.row]
    cell.elementDescriptionLabel.text = elementDescription[indexPath.row]
    cell.elementImage.image = elementImage[indexPath.row]

    // Create the shadows and modify the cards
    cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1.0)
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, cornerRadius: cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath

    return cell
}
```

Comment: `cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've set cornerRadius on cell.layer (as you have) you just need to set masksToBounds to true, because that's what tells it to adhere to the now rounded corners. (There is also no need to set invisible borders on the contentView)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // setup the cell and cast it to the custom cell created.
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.elementNameLabel.text = elemementName[indexPath.row]
    cell.elementDescriptionLabel.text = elementDescription[indexPath.row]
    cell.elementImage.image = elementImage[indexPath.row]

    // Create the shadows and modify the cards
    cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1.0)
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, cornerRadius: cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just add a rounded view on your cell, and put other things on that view.